# Extract id-specific coefficients of a multilevel ordinal regression for the different combination of factor levels

Tags: regression, mixed-model, ordinal-data

I ran this multilevel ordinal regression using `clmm` from the `ordinal` package

```
library(ordinal)
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(day=rep(seq(1,10,1),times=20), product=rep(c("A","B"),each=100),id=rep(seq(1,10,1),each=10), rating=factor(round(runif(200, 1,4)),ordered=T))

fm <- clmm(rating ~ product*day + (day:product|id), data=dat)

summary(fm)

Random effects:
 Groups Name         Variance  Std.Dev. Corr          
 id     (Intercept)  0.0019106 0.04371                
        day:productA 0.0007965 0.02822  -0.580        
        day:productB 0.0055626 0.07458  -0.991  0.464 
Number of groups:  id 10 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
productB      0.28707    0.55624   0.516    0.606
day           0.01589    0.06492   0.245    0.807
productB:day -0.01343    0.09268  -0.145    0.885

Threshold coefficients:
    Estimate Std. Error z value
1|2  -1.9412     0.4311  -4.503
2|3   0.1489     0.3947   0.377
3|4   1.8952     0.4273   4.435
```

I'd like to extract the slope for `day`:`product` for every `id` in my dataset.

Because this is ordinal regression, I would do that for every level of `rating`, for example, the `day:productA` slope for `id==1` when `rating==1`.

I found a way to [extract coefficients for each level in an ordinal CLMM model](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72807959)

```
coef_ordinal(fm)
$id
    (Intercept)  day:productA  day:productB  productB        day productB:day
1  -0.004659666  0.0067145191  0.0056847187 0.2870686 0.01588863  -0.01342732
2   0.032079220 -0.0050521232 -0.0573035325 0.2870686 0.01588863  -0.01342732
3   0.016246292 -0.0109719382 -0.0253086809 0.2870686 0.01588863  -0.01342732
4  -0.032606795  0.0077477424  0.0570931971 0.2870686 0.01588863  -0.01342732
5   0.007568091  0.0005502529 -0.0142876818 0.2870686 0.01588863  -0.01342732
6   0.035569405 -0.0161443049 -0.0588863315 0.2870686 0.01588863  -0.01342732
7   0.018484504 -0.0064397257 -0.0314621503 0.2870686 0.01588863  -0.01342732
8  -0.044520743  0.0217841351  0.0730097460 0.2870686 0.01588863  -0.01342732
9  -0.028428558 -0.0021273246  0.0536964704 0.2870686 0.01588863  -0.01342732
10 -0.001054051  0.0043805578  0.0000232408 0.2870686 0.01588863  -0.01342732
```

However, I'm not sure how to combine the different values above to get specific coefficients. For example, how can I extract the slope for `day:productA` when the `rating==1` and `id==1`?

I feel I should make use of these coefficients:

```
Threshold coefficients:
    Estimate Std. Error z value
1|2  -1.9412     0.4311  -4.503
2|3   0.1489     0.3947   0.377
3|4   1.8952     0.4273   4.435
```

but `coef_ordinal` does not include rating-specific intercepts for each `id`, only a general `(Intercept)` which I'm not sure how to interpret...